# php stdin from bash pipe and heredoc

Tags: bash, php

Can I receive input from both a pipe, and a heredoc, and use them both from within php on the command line.

I want to do something like this:

```
bash$ ls -l | php <<'code'
<?php
   echo $piped;
?>
code
```

Which should return the result of `ls -l`

Also, can I use `php -R` with heredoc input for php script?

Comment: @DaveRandom In *bash*, **Here String** needs three `<` and **Here Document** two `<`.

Comment: @Shiplu I retract my pedantry and admit defeat (in that I had never come across that in the context of bash before). Comment shall be deleted...

Comment: @DaveRandom: Pedanticism requires that you stop writing apostrophes in inappropriate places.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal I'm not even going to begin to get into a debate about the precise semantic use of the possessive apostrophe, it is a debate that will never end. You may enjoy [this](http://isthatpluralizedwithanapostrophe.com/)...

Comment: @DaveRandom: You should follow that advice... I'm not aware of any debate over when an apostrophe should be used; only of many people who get it wrong. Also please stop abusing commas.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Piping**

`ls -l | php -r 'print_r(file("php://stdin"));'`

---

**Heredoc**

```
$ php <<CODE
<?php
echo "Hello World\n";
?>
CODE
Hello World
```

---

***Combined***

```
$ ls -l | php <<'CODE'
<?php
$f = file("php://stdin");
foreach($f as $k=>$v){
echo "[$k]=>$v";
}
?>
Program Finished
CODE

[0]=><?php
[1]=>$f = file("php://stdin");
[2]=>foreach($f as $k=>$v){
[3]=>echo "[$k]=>$v";
[4]=>}
[5]=>?>
[6]=>Program Finished
Program Finished
```

**Note**: When you use *Here Documents* for `php` command the newly added `php` codes overrides the previous `stdin`

Comment: So what you are saying is that when you combine piping and heredoc, the piped part is trampled by the heredoc part, and can not be retrieved?

Comment: @BillyMoon yes. It can not be retrived.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the `-R` part of the question:

> `-R` / `--process-code`
>
> PHP code to execute for every input line. Added in PHP 5.
>
> There are two special variables available in this mode: `$argn` and `$argi`. `$argn` will contain the line PHP is processing at that moment, while `$argi` will contain the line number. <sup>[Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php)</sup>

If I understood your question right, you're looking for the `$argn` variable. Heredoc should be support by your bash.

**Edit:** Err, just invoke with the value over multiple lines:

```
$ ls -l | php -R '
printf("#%02d: %s\n", $argi, $argn);
'
```

(I think it's easier to use the single quote for the switch)

Comment: I can not figure out how to pass a heredoc to `php -R` instead of a string, and I am not sure that it is possible directly.

Comment: My bad, just try a multiline "string" instead of a heredoc. Edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: Wow, multi-line string - what a revelation. Simple, and elegant - I ad no idea... I have been spending too much time writing javascript lately!

Comment: I found that if I use `'` to define the multi-line string, I don't have to escape so much of my php code, but is there any way I can avoid escaping the `'` inside my php code - so probably use a different token to delimit a multi-line string?

Comment: @BillyMoon: Better use the single quote for the parameter with PHP code. You don'T need to escape that much.

Comment: If you need multi-line, it's probably time to move to a script, but to avoid escaping `'` you can start your script using `cat`, for example: `ls -l | php -r $(cat <<-'EOF'` and end it `EOF` then `)`. You can also play with `php <<-'EOF' -- ...` where `...` is `$()` or `<()`, or you can just put the command in the script using `proc_*` or `exec` functions. Fwiw, `php -R` has proven most useful to me from the cli.